# I get two errors that I could not solve in return ESLint and destructing

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I have two quite common problems but I do not know how to solve them in my code. I am working with ReactJS + ESLint

I tried declare the const for this but after says "query" unused.

```
  handleInputChange = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        query: this.search.value,
      },
      () => {
        if (this.state.query && this.state.query.length > 1) {
          if (this.state.query.length % 2 === 0) {
            this.getInfo();
          }
        }
      },
    );
  };
```

> Must use destructing state state assigment

And the second error is:

```
 <input
              className="inputsearch"
              placeholder="Busca en ”El Cinco Cero”"
              ref={input => (this.search = input)}
              onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            />
```

> Arrow function should not return assigment

And this:

```
<ul className = "search">
              {results.results &&
                results.results.posts.rows.map (item => {
                  return (
                    <li key = {item.title}>
                      <Link
                        to = {`/ news / day / $ {item.category.id} / $ {item.id} /`}
                        key = {item.id}>
                        {item.title}
                      </ Link>
                    </ li>
                  );
                })}
            </ ul>
```

> unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body arrow-body-style

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linter wants you to deconstruct your state in the following way :

```
const { query } = this.state
```

Now, the `query` variable will be accessible right after, making your code a little more readable :

```
handleInputChange = () => {
    const { query } = this.state;
    this.setState(
        {
            query: this.search.value,
        },
        () => {
            if (query && query.length > 1 && !query.length % 2) {
                this.getInfo();
            }
        },
    );
};
```

And for the second bit of code, you need to put function's instructions into curly braces, not parenthesis :

```
<input
    className="inputsearch"
    placeholder="Busca en ”El Cinco Cero”"
    ref={input => { this.search = input; }}
    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
/>
```

And for the third bit of code you could just remove the curly braces and the `return` statement (you can add parenthesis if you want around your inner component) :

```
<ul className="search">
    {results.results && results.results.posts.rows.map(item => 
        <li key={item.title}>
            <Link
                to={`/ news / day / ${item.category.id} / ${item.id} /`}
                key={item.id}>
                {item.title}
            </ Link>
        </li>
    )}
</ul>
```

Comment: This works perfectly! but I have edited the question, I only have one last mistake. Could you help me solve it to give you a better answer, please?

Comment: Thanks for your solution and explanation. Very clear!